# Рекурсия без многократного заброса в базу

Tags: рекурсия, php

Здравствуйте, существуют рекурсии, где цикл многократно обращается в базу данных, возможно ли обойтись другим способом? точней, обратиться один раз в базу, и массив разделить на дочерние элементы и выявить его.

Comment: Вопроса вида - а можно?

Ответ - да, можно :D

Comment: А как насчет хотя бы натолкнуть на правильный путь : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делаете примерно тоже самое - только вам самим приидется реализовывать сортировку и группировку, т.е. сначала тупо выбираете все данные таблицы, из них формируете массив, обрабатываете и формируете массив необходимых данных.

(группируете, сортируете, что вашей душе угодно, только теперь это прийдеться писать самому, БД за вас, в этом случае, сортировку и т.д. делать не будет =) )

Comment: У меня готовый массив уже заранее отсортированный и был составлен бд условиями, но вот обработать его не могу, пример бы какой нибуть :D. имеются поля id name parent_id